# Replacing column names in a pandas dataframe based on a lookup

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi I have several dataframes with column headings that vary slightly. An example of a header of a dataframe will be:

```
A1    B1    C1
```

In other dataframes the first row is called A2 or A3 etc. A1..., B1...C1 represent multi character words/labels and are not the literal column names. I want to replace the column headings based on a mapping that I have between the A1, A2, Ax, B1, B2, Bx, C1, C2, Cx etc. and A, B and C.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is position of columns same? Then simpliest is use `df.columns = ['A','B','C']`

Comment: i am thinking about solution and is possible more specify it? All columns is necessary rename? Are in same position? If not, difference is only in suffixes (Are suffixes numbers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is possible use [`indexing with str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for replace by first letter:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[0]
```

Another possible solution is create dictionary for replace, e.g.:

```
d = {x:x[0] for x in df.columns}
df = df.rename(columns=d)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - let me clarify my question